# Tableau set default value in the filter

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

1. I have a gender of a person and i want to create such filter
2. How can i set deafault "men" value in this filter?
3. When user select another value and then deselect value i need to
   return default value in the filter
4. I've already tried to create such a calculated field, but it does not work with

   `MIN({FIXED: COUNTD([gender])}) <> MIN({EXCLUDE [gender]: COUNTD([gender])}) OR MIN([gender])="men"`

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several tutorials about creating a default value for filtering (and several different techniques), one of them is this one: [Dynamic Parameters, Default Values and the Flexibility to Choose](https://sonsofhierarchies.com/dynamic-parameters-default-values-and-the-flexibility-to-choose/)

For me, if you just have to put "men" as default (I mean, not a calculated value, like today's DateTime), you can just filter man before publishing your dashboard to Tableau Server/Tableau Online and every use that navigates your content will find this value selected.